# Is it possible to improve the speechrecognizer in the Actions-on-Google simulator

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am working on a DialogFlow project building a chatbot in Dutch. When testing the bot in the Actions-on-Google simulator the biggest issue we find is that the speechrecogniser does not recognise half the number we say. The project has the Dutch locale and works fine with short strings of number but as soon as we go over 5 number in a row the speech recogniser goes funny.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Comment: Have you tried testing on a real Google Assistant device, such as a Google Home or through the Google Assistant App on your phone? The speech recognizer in the simulator doesn't perform very well, but that is usually just in the simulator.

Comment: Alphanumeric strings are not going to work very well in any language. I think you should reconsider your voice interface.